# add event listener with parameter i from loop for

Tags: javascript

I'm attaching listener to all the children of a div, how to make them to alert with their number relative to their parent. Because the function executes the actual variable i, not when attached.

```
var nodes = div.children; //10 nodes
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].onclick = function () {alert(i)}
}
```

So the only solution is to use eval('i')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a closure and pass the index

```
var nodes = div.children; //10 nodes
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    (function(index){
       nodes[index].onclick = function () {alert(index)}
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another two possible answer could be:

```
nodes[i].setAttribute('onclick','alert('+i+')');
```

or:

```
nodes[i].setAttribute('index', i);
nodes[i].onclick = function(){
    alert(this.getAttribute('index')); 
    //remember attribute index is string, so do parseInt() when required
}
```